# BASH - xargs command not found

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, xargs

I am trying to create a `BASH` script that will run a command for me. This is an example of one of the commands:

```
function systemStart {
    ./ORBMarkerDetection $1 $2 $3 | xargs -n3 java -jar ../../system/layers/out/artifacts/layers_jar/layers.jar 
}
```

But when this is ran I am getting the error (referring to the above line):

```
./runActivities.sh: line 7: xargs: command not found
```

I am able to run this command in the terminal with success so I am not sure why this will not run within a BASH script?

I am calling the function like so:

```
systemStart $PATH/1.1/cupCupboard.png $PATH/1.1/kitchenDoor.png $PATH/1.1/tap.png
```

Comment: Is the value of $PATH in the script different from in the terminal?

Comment: I'll check but the command but copied straight from the terminal. The path is the same.

Comment: I've tried hard coding the path and there is still the same issue. There doesn't seem to be any hidden extra characters either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are apparently using the variable name `PATH` for your own purposes, but you can't do that -- `PATH` is a reserved variable, and changing it will cause the shell to not find commands (not just `xargs` but basically any command).

In general, you should avoid using uppercase variable names; then you can be sure yours will never conflict with a built-in shell variable.

Answer (score 1):

(You may need to put the fully-qualified path in your script?)

The command `which` can tell you the fully-qualified path for things.

```
robert@debian:~$ which xargs
/usr/bin/xargs
```

`locate` can also tell you the location of files

Lastly, then a brute-force full filesystem search using find:

```
robert@debian:~$ find / -name "xargs" 2> /dev/null
/usr/bin/xargs
```